# Get a count of cumulative values over time

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Let's say that I have the following data.

```
dt = data.table(
  date = c("2020-10-01", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-03", "2020-10-01", "2020-10-01",
           "2020-10-03", "2020-10-04", "2020-10-04", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-05"),
  client = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
  vals = rnorm(10))

dt[order(date)]

dt2 = dt[order(date), .(sum_vals = sum(vals)), by = .(date, client)]

         date client    sum_vals
1: 2020-10-01      B  2.53737527
2: 2020-10-01      C  0.64366866
3: 2020-10-02      A  1.01776243
4: 2020-10-03      C -0.06303562
5: 2020-10-03      A  0.63702089
6: 2020-10-04      B  0.12681052
7: 2020-10-04      A  0.82889616
8: 2020-10-05      B -1.45734539
9: 2020-10-05      C  0.02594185
```

What I would like to do is get a count of cumulative clients by date.

So in this case, it looks like this.

```
         date.  acts 
1: 2020-10-01      2   # b and c we active on 10/01 or before
2: 2020-10-02      3   # a, b and c we active on 10/02 or before
3: 2020-10-03      3   # a, b and c we active on 10/03 or before
4: 2020-10-04      3   # a, b and c we active on 10/04 or before
5: 2020-10-05      3   # a, b and c we active on 10/05 or before
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this with data.table or dplyr?

Comment: are you starting from `dt` or `dt2` to get to your desired result?

Comment: Starting with dt2 since some of those values in dt need to be summed together

Comment: For future questions, please either (a) use `set.seed`, or (b) give us data with `dput(.)`. Otherwise, it's unlikely that answers will start from the same point as you (without manually scraping your data).

Answer (score 3):

We could do

```
dt2[,  .(date = unique(date), acts = unlist(lapply(unique(date),  
         function(x) uniqueN(client[date <= x]))))]
```

-output

```
          date acts
1: 2020-10-01    2
2: 2020-10-02    2
3: 2020-10-03    3
4: 2020-10-04    3
5: 2020-10-05    3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
dt2[, .(date, v=cumsum(!duplicated(client)))][, .(acts=max(v)), date]
```

output:

```
         date acts
1: 2020-10-01    2
2: 2020-10-02    3
3: 2020-10-03    3
4: 2020-10-04    3
5: 2020-10-05    3
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt2 = fread("date client    sum_vals
2020-10-01      B  2.53737527
2020-10-01      C  0.64366866
2020-10-02      A  1.01776243
2020-10-03      C -0.06303562
2020-10-03      A  0.63702089
2020-10-04      B  0.12681052
2020-10-04      A  0.82889616
2020-10-05      B -1.45734539
2020-10-05      C  0.02594185")
```

---

edit: sample timing for a larger dataset

data (~1mio rows, and 10k clients in 5y) and timing code:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nd <- 5L * 365L
nr <- 1e6L
nc <- 1e4L
dt2 <- data.table(date=sample(nd, nr, TRUE), client=sample(nc, nr, TRUE), vals=1L)[,
    .(vals=sum(vals)), keyby=.(date, client)]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=1L,
    m0={a0 <- dt2[,  .(date = unique(date), acts = unlist(lapply(unique(date),  
         function(x) uniqueN(client[date <= x]))))]},
    m1={a1 <- dt2[, .(date, v=cumsum(!duplicated(client)))][, .(acts=max(v)), date]},
    m2={a2 <- dt2[, .(clients = list(unique(client))), by = date
        ][, acts := lengths(Reduce(function(p,n) unique(c(p,n)), clients, accumulate = TRUE))]}
) #in chronological order of post
fsetequal(a0, a1)
#[1] TRUE
fsetequal(a0, a2[, clients:=NULL])
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
   m0 14293.6303 14293.6303 14293.6303 14293.6303 14293.6303 14293.6303     1
   m1    40.2999    40.2999    40.2999    40.2999    40.2999    40.2999     1
   m2  1088.7080  1088.7080  1088.7080  1088.7080  1088.7080  1088.7080     1
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

```r
dt2[, .(clients = list(unique(client))), by = date
  ][, accts := lengths(Reduce(function(p,n) unique(c(p,n)), clients, accumulate = TRUE))]
#          date clients accts
#        <IDat>  <list> <int>
# 1: 2020-10-01     B,C     2
# 2: 2020-10-02       A     3
# 3: 2020-10-03     C,A     3
# 4: 2020-10-04     B,A     3
# 5: 2020-10-05     B,C     3
```

---

Data

```r
dt2 <- setDT(structure(list(date = structure(c(18536L, 18536L, 18537L, 18538L, 18538L, 18539L, 18539L, 18540L, 18540L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), client = c("B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"), sum_vals = c(2.53737527, 0.64366866, 1.01776243, -0.06303562, 0.63702089, 0.12681052, 0.82889616, -1.45734539, 0.02594185)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

---

Benchmark,

```r
bench::mark(
  chinsoon12 = dt2[, .(date, v=cumsum(!duplicated(client)))][, .(acts=max(v)), date], 
  akrun = dt2[, .(date = unique(date), acts = unlist(lapply(unique(date), function(x) uniqueN(client[date <= x]))))], 
  r2evans = dt2[, .(clients = list(unique(client))), by = date][, accts := lengths(Reduce(function(p,n) unique(c(p,n)), clients, accumulate = TRUE))], 
  check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory        time     gc        
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>        <list>   <list>    
# 1 chinsoon12   2.17ms   2.61ms      359.    97.7KB     0      180     0      502ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3~ <bch:tm~ <tibble [~
# 2 akrun       810.3us  923.5us     1010.    48.7KB     0      505     0      500ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3~ <bch:tm~ <tibble [~
# 3 r2evans     843.7us  956.5us      913.    81.1KB     2.45   373     1      409ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3~ <bch:tm~ <tibble [~
```

Comment: Almost twice faster according to `microbenchmark` : upvoted!

Comment: Note that @akrun result seem different than yours : 2 first rows are 2 and not 2,3

Comment: I saw that. I think it's because akrun likely started with the random `dt` instead of scraping from the console output.

Comment: I didn't use any set.seed

Comment: Okay, but your output with my `dt2` produces the same output as mine, so it's a difference in the source data. Valid point for comparison, but I think all three answers produce the same valid results.

Comment: @akrun, what is the problem with me identifying your solution as being the fastest?

Comment: It is just that when somebody puts my name in a nice way, I get downvoted.

Comment: hi, can i check the size of the data used in the benchmark?

Comment: @chinsoon12 it's `dt2`, as provided in the answer. I also tried with 1000 or 10000 and found no change in *order*. But it was a little hasty, admittedly, if the OP is truly concerned about performance, a more-informed benchmark is justified.